# Error while trying to do connection between SQL Server to Pentaho User Console

Tags: sql-server, pentaho

This is really make me crazy. I try to do this since last month but until now I still cannot do any connection between `SQL Server 2000` to `Pentaho User Console`. Before this I got error in connection because it cannot found port 1433. But now after I make sure that port is enable, I got this error.

[image: error in connecting between SQL Server and Pentaho]

Why this error occur? What step I need to take to solve this error?

Comment: have you pasted your connection jar over this location? \bi-server_4.8\administration-console\jdbc

Comment: I didn't found that location. I use Pentaho Enterprise Edition. Is it the same version like said?

Comment: i am using community edition, never used enterprise edition but you have to put proper connection jar in jdbc folder for connecting to your database.

Comment: Is it connection jar that you mention is jtdc driver or it is something else? I'm using `SQL Server 2000` & `Pentaho Enterprise Edition`

Comment: yes sql server connection jar.

Comment: I already did like you told me but the same error still show up.